# when i use tween animation in app bar flexibleSpace, ios swipe navigation that time background image overlape

Tags: flutter, animation, flutter-ui

When utilizing tween animation within the flexibleSpace of the AppBar and performing swipe navigation on iOS, there is an issue where the image experiences overlap.

[this actual result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrOLH.png).

[i have expect  result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5wLH.png)

```
class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget {
@OverRide
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
backgroundColor: Colors.red,
appBar: AppBar(
flexibleSpace: CommunityBannerInAppBarWidget(),
),
body: const Center(child: Text('second Screen')),
);
}
}

class CommunityBannerInAppBarWidget extends StatefulWidget {
CommunityBannerInAppBarWidget({
Key? key,
}) : super(key: key);
@OverRide
State createState() =>
_CommunityBannerInAppBarWidgetState();
}

class _CommunityBannerInAppBarWidgetState
extends State {
@OverRide
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return TweenAnimationBuilder(
tween: Tween(begin: 1.0, end: 1.5),
duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
builder: (context, progress, child) {
return Transform.scale(scale: progress, child: 

);
},
);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to clip the content of the second page using a widget like `ClipRect`

update your second screen:

```
class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ClipRect( // add this widget 
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        appBar: AppBar(
          flexibleSpace: CommunityBannerInAppBarWidget(),
        ),
        body: const Center(child: Text('Second Screen')),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

It should look like this after the change :

[image: result]